# Сохранить график Chart C# в PDF

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, диаграммы

Как сохранить график, построенный с помощью Chart в PDF формате?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    try
            {
                if(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {

    string x = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
}
                this.chart1.SaveImage(saveFileDialog1.FileName + ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
         Document document = new Document();
         Stream myStream ;
     using (var stream = new FileStream(saveFileDialog1.FileName + ".pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))

        {
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
            document.Open();
            using (var imageStream = new FileStream(saveFileDialog1.FileName + ".png", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                var image = Image.GetInstance(imageStream);
                document.Add(image);
            }
            document.Close();
             MessageBox.Show("сохранено");
             File.Delete(saveFileDialog1.FileName + ".png");
        }
    }
            catch 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR");
            }
            }
```

**Можно сделать что-то на подобии. Мы сохраняем график в png, а потом копипастим в PDF.
Библеотеку подруби Itextsharp.dll**

Так же для удобства мы используем **SaveFileDialog**.

Comment: Как раз таки SaveFileDialog в ответе лишний. Как именно получить путь для сохранения - дело десятое, а пример замусоривает. Лучше подробней объяснить, где взять библиотеку iTextSharp, как её подключить, какие пространства имён открыть.